# Display smoothie charts plot from Google Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to display a simple smoothie chart plot (http://smoothiecharts.org/tutorial.html) in the browser from my google cloud function.

The cloud function is in node.js and it based on an http trigger.

I need help displaying the actual chart. Not sure how to tell the cloud function to display the chart in the browser.

Thanks!

Edit:

Authentication isn't an issue here. I understand how to code the smoothie functions, but I'm having trouble including the HTML code in the Node.js function.

These two lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="smoothie.js"></script>
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
```

I'm not sure how to tell the cloud function about these.

The goal is for the cloud function to return an HTML page with the graph on it.

Comment: Could you please clarify if you are looking to graph the results of calling the gcf (gcf returns only the data to graph) or to display the graph by calling the gcf (gcf return the html with the graph)?

Comment: May I know why you want to display the graph to your browser using Cloud Functions? Cloud Functions require authentication by default (but it can be changed), so you'll get '403' error if you call the HTTP URL directly from the browser because there's no auth header specified. If that's the case then there's other serverless alternatives you could try.

Answer (score 0):

cloud Functions HTTP triggered wait a request and provide a response. Quite obvious, I know. But from there, what do you need? You want to request new data and get the fresh data in the response.

To achieve this, you can start from the #4 example of the tutorial and customize it like this

```
var smoothie = new SmoothieChart();

// Data
var line1 = new TimeSeries();
var line2 = new TimeSeries();

// Add a random value to each line every second
setInterval(function() {
  line1.append(##CALL FUNCTION TO GET AND PARSE VALUES FOR LINE1##);
  line2.append(##CALL FUNCTION TO GET AND PARSE VALUES FOR LINE2##);
}, 1000);

// Add to SmoothieChart
smoothie.addTimeSeries(line1);
smoothie.addTimeSeries(line2);

smoothie.streamTo(document.getElementById("mycanvas"));
```

I don't know more about your data, and framework that you usually use to call function from JS. It's also important to know if the user is authenticated or not: Cloud functions can be deployed in private mode and all the request need to be authenticated and authorized in this case.

Comment: Thank you. I understand this part, but where do I put the HTML code defining "my canvas"?

Comment: To host the static code, you can put in Google Cloud Storage, or on App Engine. You can also have a Cloud Functions that serve this static code.

Comment: Can the same cloud function serve the html code?

Comment: I think you can, I saw people do this and I find this not very clean. That's why I can't recommend this. Cloud Functions are designed to be single purpose. Here you serve HTML and Data. I would recommend to build a webserver, with 2 endpoint (HTML and Data) and to deploy it on App Engine or Cloud Run